# Get number of data points in visible range

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a particular Matplotlib graph I want the linestyle to change dynamically based on the number of points on screen (basically, switch from `-` to `-o` when there are sufficiently low number on data points).

For that, first I need to get the number of data points on screen. I wrote a code sample below that does that using the function `get_view_interval`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_Npoints_on_screen(ax=None, line_index=0):
    ''' 
    Input
    -----
    ax: matplotlib axe
    l: line number
    '''

    if ax is None:
        ax=plt.gca()
    line = ax.get_lines()[line_index]


    xmin, xmax = ax.xaxis.get_view_interval()
    ymin, ymax = ax.yaxis.get_view_interval()

    xdata = line.get_xdata()
    ydata = line.get_ydata()

    return sum((xdata>=xmin) & (xdata<=xmax) & (ydata>=ymin) & (ydata<=ymax))


# Just a figure to play with
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from numpy import linspace, pi, cos
    x = linspace(0,4*pi,100)

    plt.plot(x,cos(x),'ok')

    print(get_Npoints_on_screen(),'points on screen')

    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
    plt.xlim((0,pi))

    print(get_Npoints_on_screen(),'points on screen')
```

It works, but I don't find it very elegant. Is there a more straightforward way of getting the number of visible points on screen in Matplotlib?

Comment: I would consider this to be a good solution. The number of points in the view will always depend on the artists being drawn, so a function that finds this number will always need to take the artist as input. That's what you are doing here. The way it is done is also not dramatically inefficient, so there is no real need to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Could you not just count the number of data points within your axis limits?

Comment: @mmensing that's pretty much what I'm doing with `sum(...)` but there may be a better way. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you for your input too.

Comment: Note that using numpy `(... & ... & ...).sum()` is *much* quicker than `sum(... & ... & ...)` when you're plotting lots of data (from about 5 seconds to 100 milliseconds).